Using stdin for tar files content
Is it possible to use tar to create a archive completely in memory?
I mean, you can pipe file names into tar's stdin, which are then used to create the archive. But i want to also pipe the file content via stdin to tar.
Pseudo code/usage:
echo "file-name.txt" | tar cfzv backup.tgz --files-from=-
echo "Hello World | tar cfzv backup.tgz --files-from=-

I know the example above executes tar twice.
Its just to demonstrate what i want, first tell tar the file name i want in the archive, then the files content. (Or with a special syntax/control char: echo "filename.txt\zHello World | tar cfzv backup.tgz --files-from=- or something like that)
I dont want to use anything on the filesystem.
Tar should read from stdin, do its job, and write to stdout.

"completely in memory" – tmpfs is in memory. Create files there and proceed normally.


Is it possible to use tar to create a archive completely in memory?

tar
No, tar is designed to store file metadata like ownership and access-permissions as well as names. It needs access to a filesystem from which it can read that sort of information.
shar
You might find a shell-archive does what you want. See shar. The file format might be easier to create than tar.
uuencode & uudecode
Failing that, I might use uuencode on the data and write a series of uudecode commands and "here documents" into a file.
security considerations
Here be dragons.
